# MySql query not working with variables weird bug

Tags: php, sql

I have a list of users ids and my goal is to get the name of each user using the id

the sql variable prints: SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '56d4814fb37cf3.17691034 '

If i copy paste the query the name is returned and works as well with other ids, but i don't want the function to allways return the same name, i want to add the variable $userID to my query and return the name

But this only works when i hardcode de id

```css
public function returnNameByID($userID){
 //User ID: 56d4814fb37cf3.17691034 
 
    $sql =  "SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$userID'";
 
  echo $sql; // Prints SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '56d4814fb37cf3.17691034 '
 
//Doesn't work $name returns Null
//  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$userID'"); 

//Doesn't work $name returns Null
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 

// Works $name returns name of the user
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(" SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '56d4814fb37cf3.17691034 ' "); 

    $stmt->execute();
 
    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
 
    $name = $result["name"];

    return $name;
```

**EDIT**

```css
require_once 'db_functons.php';
$db = new db_functions();

$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$mArray =  array();

$mArray = $db->getFriendsList($userID);
//Printing the array Prints the correct id's

$name = $db->returnNameByID($mArray[0]);
echo $name;
```

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: `'56d4814fb37cf3.17691034 '` see that trailing space? Remove it.

Comment: this line works: $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(" SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '56d4814fb37cf3.17691034  ' "); removing the space makes no diference, but this //  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$userID'");  and this $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);  don't

Comment: `$userID` failed you then and you need to find out why http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and probably a variable scope issue also.

Comment: try using this QOUTE SYMBOL **`** instead of **'**

Comment: didn't work, i have updated the code above, i am getting the ids from a file, and i store the ids on an array, if a pass a string it works but it's not working when i use the array

Comment: i used echo gettype ($mArray[0]); prints string

Comment: The problem is that the `$userID` in the function has some random blank characters on the end of it. On the first line of your function `$userID = trim($userID);`

Comment: it works with $userID = trim($userID); Thanks Alot Matt, i don't undertand why it works when i manually write the query with the space but if i use the variable without triming it doens work i don't understand the diference but i am only a begginer, once again thanks alot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems  you have some space around your code try using a trim

```
$sql =  "SELECT name FROM users WHERE trim(unique_id) = '" . trim($userID) . "';";
```

Comment: Yay, someone gets it. One thing that I would suggest is just adding that you should probably bind the parameter $userID rather than inserting it directly into the query (just good practice)

Comment: Yes in some case the string construction is not clear and  in  the way i proposed the evaluation of the var  content is explicitally clear ..